# ¿Cómo "reiniciar un programa"?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Disculpen quiero saber como podría hacer que se repitiera la ejecución.

```
int main(){
cout << "Elija una opción" <<"\n (1) Añadir tanque." <<"\n (2) Ver calculo de los tanques." ;
cin >> opcion;
if(opcion==1)
    Fn_addtanq();
else
    Fn_Totaltanq(); 

}
int Fn_addtanq(){
tanq=0;
cout << "Introduzca galones usados: "; 

cin >> galus;

cout << "Introduzca millas recorridas: "; 

cin >> millm;

divtanq=millm/galus;
printf("Tanque %d = %f",tanq,divtanq);
tanq++;
```

Quiero que después de añadir un tanque tuviera la posibilidad de añadir otro, pero no sé como. Además quisiera saber como podría ir guardando los datos en el caso de añadir un 2do tanque. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es envolver el código del `main` con un bucle `while` y entonces se ejecutará hasta que el usuario pulse en una opción (por ejemplo, añadir la opción `(3) Salir`).

Algo como esto (sólo el código relevante):

```
int main(){
    // inicializamos opción a 0
    opcion = 0;
    // mientras el usuario no seleccione la opción de salida (3), se ejecuta el código
    while (opcion != 3) {
        cout << "Elija una opción" 
             << "\n (1) Añadir tanque."  
             << "\n (2) Ver calculo de los tanques." 
             << "\n (3) Salir del programa.";
        cin >> opcion;
        if(opcion==1)
            Fn_addtanq();
        else
            Fn_Totaltanq(); 
    }
}
```

Nota: asumo que tu código funciona. La variable `opcion` parece ser global (no veo dónde se define en tu código) y yo no la he definido en la solución de arriba.

Comment: Genio, tengo otro problema en Fn_Totaltanq()  se deben sumar el total de millas y galones para dividirlos. ¿Cómo podría guardar las millas y galones que se ingresan en un tanque y sumarlos si se añade otro?

Answer (score 0):

Añadido a lo que dice @alvaro-montoro, yo usaría do-while, el cual es mas elegante para menús.

El bucle do-while, a diferencia del while, evalúa la condición después de ejecutarse. Eso permite que siempre se realice al menos una ejecución del código, evitando asi inicializaciones forzosas de la variable control.

Con esto, el codigo indicado antes quedaria asi:

`int main(){
    // mientras el usuario no seleccione la opción de salida (3), se ejecuta el código
   do{
        cout << "Elija una opción" 
             << "\n (1) Añadir tanque."

             << "\n (2) Ver calculo de los tanques." 
             << "\n (3) Salir del programa.";
        cin >> opcion;
        if(opcion==1)
            Fn_addtanq();
        else
            Fn_Totaltanq(); 
    } while (opcion != 3);
}`